# Why doesn't post won't save to page when refreshing?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb, express

Using Javascript, NodeJS, MongoDB, Express

In my app a user is suppose to type in the input field and when they click the submit button the text gets appended to the page.  I am able to successfully post text to the page but when I refresh my browser, my post do not show up.  I think I need to do a get request through ajax in the script section of my partials/test.ejs, but I am unsure how to execute this.
models/Blog.js

```
 var
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema,
  BlogSchema = new Schema({
  name: String

 })
var Blog = mongoose.model('Blog', BlogSchema)
module.exports = Blog
```

views/partials/test.ejs

```
<body>
<form>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="create">Submit</button>
</form>
<div class="feedback-messages"></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var messages = $('.feedback-messages')
var postItem = $("#create")


postItem.on('click', function(evt) {
 evt.preventDefault();


  $.ajax({
    url: '/test',
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({data: newItem})
  })
    .done(function(data) {
      console.log("Hello");
      messages.append(newItem)
})
```

routes/index.js

```
var
  express = require('express');
  router = express.Router();
  bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  mongoose = require('mongoose');
  Blog = require('../models/Blog.js');
// route for home page

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('./partials/home');
});

//route for test page
router.get('/test', function(req, res) {
 res.render('./partials/test');
   });



router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));



router.get('/test', function(req, res){
    Blog.find({}, function(err, blog){
        if(err) return console.log(err)
        res.json(blog);
    })
});


router.post('/test', function(req, res){
    // console.log(req.body)
    Blog.create({content: req.body.data}, function(err, item){
        if(err) return console.log(err)
        res.json({serverSays: "Request received. Added item.", item: item})
    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: can I see your table structure?

Answer (score 0):

try changing you code for saving into this

```
    Blog.create({content: req.body.data})
    .then(function(item){
        res.json({serverSays: "Request received. Added item.", item: item})
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        return console.log(err)
    })
```